# How to call function from php class in function from web page

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, web

Code example;

PHP Web Page: (index.php)

```
 <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    include("class_validation.php");
    $val = new validation();

        if(isset($_POST['action'])) doSomething();

    function doSomething() {
        $val->validate(); //I AM UNABLE TO DO THIS!
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP file: (class_validation.php)

```
<?php
class validation()
{
    function validate(){
        //some validation
    }
}
?>
```

QUESTION: How can I call a function from the 'class_validation.php' file in a function I created in my PHP web page? I can correctly call the function doSomething() as well as call the function $val->validate(); when not located in another function. I there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$val` is out of scope in that `doSomething()` function call. Pass it as a parameter to the function:

```
// Define the function to accept a parameter. Use a type hint to be sure it is 
// a validation object
function doSomething(validation $val) {
  $val->validate(); 
}

if(isset($_POST['action'])) doSomething($val);
```

([PHP documentation on type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php))

Alternatively, and ***not recommended***, you may use the `global` keyword inside the function to reference the global `$val`.

```
function doSomething() {
  // Don't do it this way. The func parameter is preferred
  global $val;
  $val->validate(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be looking for closure support, which are only available for [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

And according to your code sample, it doesn't seems  to be a right use case. Maybe you should just pass this value as function parameter ?